# Query in SQL to sum the top nth largest of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I have two columns I care about `YearMonth` and `Value`.

How can I sum the 50th (1st to 50th, i.e. 1st, 2nd, ..., 50th) largest values from `Value` and create a new column based on the criteria?

I am able to do `SUM(CASE WHEN Value > 100 THEN Value END) AS LargeValue` but the 1st to 50th largest value change every `YearMonth`, so doing this wouldn't be completely right.

I couldn't find any solutions for this, and most replies finds rather than the sum the n'th largest.

The table looks like this (simplified):

```
====================
YearMonth Value Flow
====================
201801   500   10
201801   400   -5
 ...     ...   ...
201802   700   20
201802   100  -20 
201802   50    10
```

Comment: Do a sum on a smaller Select where you order by value and do a rownum < 50 or something

Comment: could you just give us a sample output for your given input and the SQL RDBMS you are working like Oracle SQL server etc

Comment: I do not have a sample output yet, because I am not sure how to start creating the query. However, I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when seqnum <= 50 then value end) over
           (partition by yearmonth) as top50_sum
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by yearmonth order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

If you just want one row per `yearmonth` in the result set, then use `group by`:

```
select t.yearmonth, sum(value) as top50_sum
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by yearmonth order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 50
group by yearmonth
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used a derived table ordering the row by value descending and limiting the result to 50 rows. Then take the sum from that.

How the limiting is written depends on the DBMS. In many of them `LIMIT` will work.

```
SELECT sum(x.value)
       FROM (SELECT t.value
                    FROM elbat t
                    ORDER BY t.value DESC
                    LIMIT 50) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.r < 51 THEN t.value ELSE 0 END) OVER() runningtotal 
  FROM (
         SELECT a.yearmonth, 
                a.value, 
                RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value DESC) r 
           FROM yourtable a ) t 
 ORDER BY t.r asc
```

Firts creating a ranked table order than creating a runningtotal column for the ranked table only for the first 50 elements.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but I got `Failed. 4104: The multi-part identifier "a.Value" could not be bound`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mataunited18, corrected it should have been a.value in the outer select.